# HTTP POST/GET on ServiceMix

Tags: apache-camel, httprequest, esb, apache-servicemix

In the broadest sense, I have numerous Web Service which the user sends HTTP Post commands to, and returns XML results back.  The problem is they all sit on separate Tomcat servers, making the URLs are completely different and hard to keep track; and the XML results of each service are different formats and require different parsing methods.  I want to utilize ServiceMix's NMR, and Camel's routing mechanism to send all these HTTP Requests to one source, and have it parse the result before sending it back.  I have the Camel routing mechanism working, but right now it's another WAR file, which sits on another Tomcat server.  How would I migrate this to ServiceMix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache ServiceMix can deploy WAR applications, so you can try just by copying the .war file to the deploy directory.

Comment: I tried that and doesn't work.  I thought in order to do that, you need to convert it to an OSGi bundle.  Know any good documentation on how to do that?

Comment: Not all WAR files is supported as the base container is OSGi based, and if the WAR uses some "magic" classloading, then it may not work. For example Apache Tapestry do not work with OSGi.